# Cross Currency equivalent swap

Tags: cross-currency-basis

I am reaching out for some help to get an equivalent basis in another currency.

I would like to buy a FRN with a current spread SONIA 1M + 35 bps.

And I would like to have the equivalent spread in EURIBOR 3M for euro currency.

I am a total beginner and have a few knowledge on this subject and would really appreciate your precious help (and if possible the steps of conversions)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi, you will need some sort of EUR-GBP Cross Currency Basis adjustment. What is the compounding frequency of your SONIA FRN? What is EUR3M? 3m Euribor?

Comment: Hello KevinT, thanks for your reply! This would be SONIA 1M against 3m Euribor indeed.
Thanks again for your help

Comment: It's an interesting time to ask this question; in fact, the Xccy market has moved (for most currencies) to RFR-based basis swaps very recently (21 Sep). So in your case, it might be sensible to start with the GBP/USD basis from SONIA-SOFR swap. Then next infer the EUR/USD basis (either from Euribor-vs-USD Libor or even ESTR-vs-SOFR swaps, while in the latter case you could as a last step infer Euribor 3m from ESTR-Euribor single ccy basis swaps). That should give you a good proxy for the GBP/EUR basis (slight error due to the 1m compounding; afaik, there are no market instruments for this).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer KevinT!